# Date Column Split in Talend

Tags: date, talend

So I have one big file (13 million rows) and date formatted as:
`2009-04-08T01:57:47Z`. Now I would like to split it into 2 columns now,
one with just date as `dd-MM-yyyy` and other with time only `hh:MM`.

How do I do it?

Comment: Well, in which programming language do you plan to tackle that problem?

Comment: Java or Python, i would like for it to be reliable and quick...and within talend Data Integration platform

Comment: Great - So, what have you tried so far? How your code looks like?
You have to present some examples, problems, error messages etc. - otherwise people won't help you with your issue.

Comment: Ok, I tried to use tsplit and tmap features in talend. although i just cant get my head around. I used some ETL platforms. so using tmap i have TalendDate.formatDate("dd-MM-yyyy",row1.timestamp) but when i test it i got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

Comment: timestamp is "2009-04-08T01:57:47Z" column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use tMap and parseDate/formatDate to do what you want. It is neither necessary nor recommended to implement your own date parsing logic with regexes.

First of all, parse the timestamp using the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. Then you can use the parsed Date to output the formatted date and time information you want:

- `dd-MM-yyyy` for the date
- `HH:mm` for the time (Note: you mixed up the case in your question, `MM` stands for the month)

If you put that logic into a tMap:

[image: Using tMap to split a timestamp into date and time columns]

you will get the following:

- Input:

  - timestamp `2009-04-08T01:57:47Z`
- Output:

  - date `08-04-2009`
  - time `01:57`

**NOTE**

Note that when you parse the timestamp with the mentioned format string (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`), the time zone information is not parsed (having 'Z' as a literal). Since many applications do not properly set the time zone information anyway but always use 'Z' instead, so this can be safely ignored in most cases.

If you need proper time zone handling and by any chance are able to use Java 7, you may use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` instead to parse your timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing Talend is falling over on the T and Z part of your date time stamp but this is easily resolved.

As your date time stamp is in a regular pattern we can easily extract the date and time from it with a tExtractRegexFields component.

You'll want to use `"^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}):[0-9]{2}Z"` as your regex which will capture the date in yyyy-MM-dd format and the time as mm:HH (you'll want to replace the date time field with a date field and a time field in the schema).

Then to format your date to your required format you'll want to use a tMap and use `TalendDate.formatDate("dd-MM-yyyy",TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row7.date))` to return a string in the dd-MM-yyyy format.